# BS4 not finding element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/news/world'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

l = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'module module_ls ls ni noImage'})
a = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'subPrev headline'})

print(l)
print(a)
```

This returns empty lists. But as you can see in the image, there exist div with those classes... Why?

[image: element inspection of website]

Answer (score 0):

With `lxml` parser it works:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

Of course you have to install lxml. If you have `html5lib` it also works with the page:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working either. Does it work for you?

Comment: Nope. And that's strange.

Comment: It seems bs4 failed to parse MSIE conditionals. I downloaded the page, removed code between the second `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` and its `<![endif]-->` — and even your code works with the fixed page. Perhaps a bug in BS. It'd be noce if you create a *small* example page and send it to BS bugtracker.

Comment: Or may be the bug isn't in bs4 but in `html.parser`. Let's try lxml… Works! See updated answer.

Comment: @phd The proper way to call the parser is `html5lib` and not `html5`.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Edited, though I'm pretty sure I ran the code with 'html5'.

Comment: @phd but didn't you got a message from `BeautifulSoup` as soon as the code ran?

Comment: There was no error. May be there was a warning, but the prints were so long they moved any warning out of view and I didn't scroll my terminal.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar You are right. The warning is:  UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib").